# Estimator for the propensity for consumption c = C/Y

Tags: self-study, estimation, proportion, survey, estimators

I've an exercise where it asks to propose an estimator for the propensity for consumption: $c = C/Y$ where $C$ is the consume and $Y$ is the income.

Since the consumption function $C = c_0 + c_1 Y$ is a linear curve and in particular recalls the simple linear regression $y = a + bx$, I would have solved it this way: $\hat{c} = Cov(C,Y)/Var(Y)$.

Is it right?

## **UPDATE**

I have watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rv4nbRQq7r8) that explains the derivation of $c_1$.

Infact, the Youtuber proceeds in the following way:
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial c_1} = 0 + c_1 \cdot 1 = \hat{c_1}
$$

Is this the estimator that the exercise was asking for?

I feel a little confused because this procedure is just easy. I would need me an estimator like MLE in the statistical inference, but I don't know how to work Econometrics. I hope I've understood myself.

## **FINAL**

I've solved the issue. In practice, I had to divide the consumption function by $Y$:

$C = c_0 + c_1 Y$

$\dfrac{C}{Y} = \dfrac{c_0}{Y} + c_1$

If I assume $c_0 = 0$, the estimator is equal to $c_1 = c$.

Thanks @dimitriy for your contribution.

Comment: I think it depends on whether you want average (your C/Y) or marginal (dC/dY). Which is it?

Comment: @dimitriy the focus is an estimator for the ratio $c = C/Y$ that you define average propensity of consume. Will it be this?

Comment: Hint: Start with your equation for C that is a linear function of Y.  Divide through by Y to get C/Y. What does that look like? Also, you should probably add the homework tag.

Comment: @dimitriy was one of the first thoughts, but I'm reading "propose an estimator" I had thought about it asked for something specific. It was quite easy in the end. Thank you for your helpfulness.